# Why scrolling via scrollBy() does not work in Vue component update hook?

Tags: vue.js, scroll, vue-component

The code does nothing, but the instruction in console on the element works.

```
updated: function () {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
        this.$el.scrollBy(0, 1000)
})
```

Test `this.$el.style.backgroundColor = "red"` works without any problems. 
I have no idea what's wrong. Thanks for help!

Comment: Are you sure that your element, `this.$el`, actually is scrollable?

Comment: I think, used overflow-y: scroll; and as I said scrollBy works perfectly in console

Comment: Could you please add a reproducible example of your code?

Comment: TBH I really don't know what could be a reproducible example in that case beacuse idk what exactly should I show. Instead of that I prefer to send a git repo: https://github.com/InverMN/xlink-webchat , the problem takes place at src/components/Messages.vue